# Colours of clickable links in webdesign

Tags: website-design, hyperlinks, color-scheme, flat-design

This is a redesign of my website im doing:

http://www.ryansmurphy.com/redesign/

As you can see, its largely a work in progress, im trying to do a flat ui design.

I can tell you now, I am in no way a designer or UI, UX expert, im a developer, traditionally useless at design, but giving it my best shot.

you can see on the main content, there are three links, under the title, latest blog posts, i have made them red, the same color as my header, but not sure this looks right, is it ok? should it be more contrasting, the standard blue? any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Hi Ryan, this is an aesthetics question and seems better suited for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chris is right that this is partly an aesthetics question, but there is still a usability angle under there. Ryan, as long as you pick one hyperlink color and use it consistently wherever there is a link you'll be fine. It's also ok to use your header color, I think, because the layout isn't blending them together and you have icons for the navigation.

One other piece of advice is type hierarchy and how that has an impact on flat design. Looking at your Projects page, the headline and the following links are same the pixel height. That makes me think your header is a dead link. You might want to reduce the link text size (maybe to 24px?) as making them subservient will let the user they are in a section and this is its available content. It will also contrast the link more from the other type on the page.

Comment: OMG - thanks man for your help. I appreciate. Literally the most beautiful thing I have ever read, hopefully like my site will be :)